# Transpose 2D array structure

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, transpose

I don't think this can be done (with out my own function), however I'll ask any way.

I have a array in PHP like

```
array(
  'item1' => array(
               'Hello',
               'Good',
               ),
  'item2' => array(
               'World',
               'Bye',
               ),
  )
```

The individual fields come from a web form

I want to rearrange it to the following

```
array(
  array(
    'item1' => 'Hello',
    'item2' => 'World',
     ),
  array(
    'item1' => 'Good',
    'item2' => 'Bye',
     ),
  )
```

Make an array of objects from the field arrays

I could write a function to do this.

However I was wondering can one of the **built-in array functions** achieve this for me?

Comment: No, there is no built-in function that does *this particular* transformation. You could cobble together a few existing functions though to make them do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no built in function that would do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in function to do this - but here is a user-defined one that will:

```
function convert_array ($array) {
  $result = array();
  foreach ($array as $key => $inner) {
    for ($i = 0; isset($inner[$i]); $i++) {
      $result[$i][$key] = $inner[$i];
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/elvh8cNs)

Answer (score 1):

Most certainly not the most efficient, but as close to *"one function"* as you'll get. ;)

```
array_map(function ($i) use ($array) { return array_combine(array_keys($array), $i); }, call_user_func_array('array_map', array_merge(array(function () { return func_get_args(); }), $array)));
```

See http://codepad.viper-7.com/xIn3Oq.

Comment: Oh, and don't use this in production without 10 pages of documentation on what it does. ;)